# The distribution of the sum of values from a normal and a truncated normal distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics

Using R to extract truncated normal distribution samples and normal distribution samples separately, when they are combined, the image drawn by the hist function is very similar to a normal distribution. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not this distribution has a simple bell shape will depend very much on the parameters; it will typically be bimodal (with two local maxima rather than one single); in any case, the procedure to calculate it is described in [The Sum of Values from a Normal and a Truncated Normal Distribution](https://doi.org/10.2307/1266101).